# How do I burn multiple Ubuntu isos on one DVD?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, iso

I always find it a waste putting a 790MB Ubuntu iso on a 4GB DVD, and I was wondering how to put multiple operating systems on one DVD with a grub menu.
I know it is possible, but I just don't know how!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if it can be done from within Ubuntu ( that I know of), but you can use MagicISO.  The only problem it is Windows based.  If you have access to a windows machine, it, you can take a look at it.

> MagicISO has ability to create Multi-Bootable CD/DVD image file so
>   that the user can incorporate multiple installation CD into one
>   CD/DVD, and install multiple Operation System from one CD/DVD.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source: [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-createmultibootcd.htm)</sup>

Comment: It even works on Wine :)

Answer (score 5):

Even though there's already an accepted answer i'll add this solution as well for the sake of completeness. And also coz' this answer better describes what's happening 'under the hood', so to speak. [Creating Multi-Boot Discs](http://www.linuxforu.com/2009/08/create-multiboot-discs/).

Comment: This is a URL link only answer. Moreover, the how to in the link shows what to do for various other distributions other than Ubuntu. It is not clear what the corresponding copying files steps would be for Ubuntu. Please describe the essential steps from the link and tailor it for Ubuntu ISOs.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use the [Ubuntu AIO DVD](http://fcmam5-aio.blogspot.fr/2014/05/ubuntu-aio-dvd-1404-collection-of-most.html), a collection of the most important Ubuntu 14.04 LTS flavors.

Made by Milan Rajcic and Nihil Enochian, Ubuntu AIO (All-in-One) DVD is an open source distribution of Linux which  includes multiple editions of the world's most popular Ubuntu editions: Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu GNOME, Xubuntu and Lubuntu in one AIO DVD.

Five Ubuntu releases on One Disk
As mentioned, the distribution includes five different Ubuntu editions :

```
Ubuntu
Kubuntu
Ubuntu GNOME
Xubuntu
Lubuntu
```

You can download Ubuntu AIO DVD from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuaiodvd/files/14.04/).

Answer (score 0):

A program called [multiCD](http://multicd.us/) can rebuild popular Distros to a bootable ISO with a GRUB menu, plus it works within Ubuntu.