# Burning Ubuntu Download onto DVD for installation purposes

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 into my download files.

---

The download consisted of 3 ISO files.

I attempted to burn those three files onto one DVD in order to install Ubuntu onto my computer.

After the first file was burned onto the DVD it was automatically finalized and ejected from the burner.

I had to burn each of the three ISO files onto separate DVDs.  I am unable to find a way to burn all three files onto one DVD.  The DVD is of 4.7 Gb size and should have enough space for all three files.

I suspect that Ubuntu installation wants all three files on one disk. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure ubuntu.com only offers a single .iso for the ubuntu release you choose to download.

Comment: You can find the answer here

http://askubuntu.com/questions/265558/how-do-i-burn-multiple-ubuntu-isos-on-one-dvd

Comment: ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso should be 883MB in size. Which files did you download and from which URL?

Comment: use a UBS flash drive instead and don't install 13.10 install 14.04 or 12.04 LTS instead