# ISOs inside of ISOs

Tags: dual-boot, iso

Using UCK, can I bundle an ISO like Kaspersky Rescue Disk into a new Ubuntu LTS based ISO so that when the system is installed from the new ISO Kaspersky ISO is already present and bootable from GRUB?

I am building a specifically multi boot oriented system that will allow users to cope with boot problems out of the box in Windows, Debian, or Ubuntu bases. I want to include boot access to several live utilities if possible for new users who have no virtualization option.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/265558/367990

Comment: Will a MultiBootUSB work for you? you can boot multiple OS from one drive: [MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/), [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), both work good.

Comment: I am using UCK to build an ISO. I assume if other separate ISO utilities are to be included in that ISO I would have to add them as files in their proper folders i/e grub-imageboot images, grml boot, and 40_custom as the case may be, but I want Kaspersky to locate and load from a separate small NTFS partition set up by the installer of the ISO I'm trying to build. I will include virtualization alternatives in the ISO but not all users (older hardware) will be able to use that option. The object is to eliminate multiboot issues with a distro containing all the necessary utilities.